# How to fix Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffeefc00000) in XCODE with banking program?

Tags: c++

I've been asked to complete a challenge which follows:

[image]

The code I've been given to complete this task is:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS =8;
int main()
{
   int AccountNumber[MAXACCOUNTS] = {1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342};
   double Balance[MAXACCOUNTS] = {4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0, 7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44};
    int DaysSinceDebited[MAXACCOUNTS] = {20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; (i < Balance[MAXACCOUNTS - 1]); i++)
    {
        if ((Balance[i] > 10000) || (DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30))
        {
            Balance[i] = Balance[i] * 1.06;
        }
        else
        {
            Balance[i] = Balance[i] * 1.03;
        }
    }
    cout << Balance[i];

    return 0;
}
```

I'm programming XCODE and it's basically the first time I have done so but I receive the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffeefc00000) over line 21, have I done the or statement incorrectly or is it accessing somewhere out of memory?

Part 2:

How can I display the information as follows:

[image]

Comment: Which line is 21?

Comment: Don't worry, it was an error to do with my loop, but line 21 was the 'if' statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test condition in your `for` loop is really bizarre! You only need to loop with `i` having values from `0` to `MAXACCOUNTS - 1`.

So, instead of this:

```c
for (i = 0; (i < Balance[MAXACCOUNTS - 1]); i++) // Nothing to do with the VALUE of any "Balance"!
```

simply use this:

```c
for (i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
```

As it stands, your `for` loop will run up to an `i` value of `107863` (taking the value of `Balance[7]` and truncating to an int), which - of course - will run way beyond the *actual* bounds of the arrays.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you need to put the `cout << Balance[i];` line **inside** the `for` loop - move it up one line, before the closing `}`.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: The `cout` line will still access out-of-bounds.

Comment: Ok, this is now fixed, the second part of the challenge is to turn the three arrays into structs, how would I go about doing this? @Adrian Mole

Comment: @1201 Well spotted! (I missed that - but see edit.)

Comment: Also, would you know how to display the results now of that shown in the image in the question, it's under part 2 @AdrianMole

Comment: @Henry No problem! Now, what I would *suggest* (but it's really up to you) is that you 'clean up' (delete) the comments here that are no longer required (or the 'Community' may do that for you, otherwise) and also mention in your new question that it is a follow-up to this one. I'll work on an answer to that, but I want to be careful to stick within the guidelines for 'homework' provided [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/10871073). (There's also a favourite show of mine on TV just now, so please allow me some time!)

Comment: @AdrianMole Ok done that, no worries, it's not homework, just revision for a programming test I have coming up, so just needed to revise and try complete these challenges!